# symfony form validation on no object

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I browsed all the docs but still no propper solution.

I have a simple form with inputs:
username
email
gender
password

there is an entity for that signup, but there are a lot of other fields that are not in the form.

How can I create validation for it?
even a simple array or new object just for this specific form validation.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use the validation mappings on your entity and use this for validation. Only fields which are sent trough the form are validated, all other extra fields not in the form, should be ignored.

If you have no entity, simple create a model object under `Form\Model` namespace. The corresponding form type is built in the same way as a form type for an entity.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Model;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Export
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Date
     */
    protected $from;

    /**
     * @Assert\Date
     */
    protected $to;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and use it the same as en entity in your controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ExportType(), new Export());
```

Comment: is there an option to simply create an object for that specific task? for example a contact form, there is no entity for it in DB, but still I need to verify its data.

Comment: Yes simple create a "model" object under Form\Model namespace and add in it your assert annotations.

Comment: thanks good idea, if you could just edit your answer with an example I could choose this answer